# Plink output: Get multiple nls output from single table in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a [plink R2 output file](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/ld.shtml) and I want to get coef nls output from these.

A plink output file has 7 colums:

```
CHR_A, BP_A, SNP_A, CHR_B, BP_B, SNP_B, R2
```

Plink calculated the R2 for every 100kb, now I want to plot these values (within the 100kb) in a nls plot and get the coef value according to the formula:

> y=exp(a*x)

`y` will then be all the R2 values within 100kb and `x` is the distance between the markers. Similar to this is the graph on page 9 of [this PowerPoint](http://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~mcclean/plsc731/Linkage%20Disequilibrium%20-%20Association%20Mapping%20in%20Plants-lecture-overheads.pdf).

My file consists of 9 chromosomes and the R2 is calculated over every SNP distances of 100kb. So the distance goes from low to maximum 100kb and then to the next 100kb starting with low to 100kb again. So within my file there are a lot of nls calculations to be done. How can I do this so that it will take one 100kb distance at a time and then go to the next one.

What I had in mind was this:

```
data<-read.table("myfile.ld",header=TRUE)
data$distance<-with(data,data$BP_B-data$BP_A)

for (i in "every 100kb apart")
{
  fit[i]<-as.vector(coef(nls(y~exp(a*x,
     control=list(wanOnly=TRUE),start=list(a=-0.05)))))
 }
```

in which `y=data$R2` per `i` and `x=data$distance` per `i`.

The fit will then be a list with only the coef values for every 100kb distance from my plink file. But now how to get this for every 100kb?

Anyone has any idea how?

Comment: You can give a look to this post: https://fabiomarroni.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/estimate-decay-of-linkage-disequilibrium-with-distance/

You have to feed the distance and LD values to the R functions therein and the calculation will be done.

However, I don't think your data set is optimal. Slide 9 of the ppt you refer to has distances as great as several Mb, while you are only providing LD calculations at distances shorter than 100Kb. You first need to compute LD between SNPs that are at various distances, including > 100Kb.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your reply, but how do I feed the distance and LD values to the R functions in a easy way as my data is really big. Can I write a for-loop for this, but then the question is how? And the 100kb is really the maximum for the purpose of my research question, so would be great if I could keep it that distance.